# What object is visible in the background of the Dragon view from the CRS-17 launch?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object

In the livestream of the CRS-17 Mission, [at 28:02 into the livestream](https://youtu.be/AQFhX5TvP0M?t=1682) (T+13:02) there is a flashing object visible in the bottom, left third of the screen. This object moves "up" in the frame. It is visible until 28:14 (T+13:14), when the camera angle changes.

What is this?

Comment: It would be great if someone with 150+ reputation created and added the [tag:crs-17] tag.

Comment: We generally don't make tags for every mission.  That would be hundreds of tags, most of which would have few or no questions.  Exceptions include Apollo flights and telescopes/probes/orbiters/landers/rovers with major scientific missions, as these each generate plenty of questions.

Comment: @Tim but you don't always need rights to reuse copyrighted media because there is [fair use](https://www.youtube.com/intl/en-GB/yt/about/copyright/fair-use/#yt-copyright-four-factors). Your posting of this image would fall under the aspect of educational/research which qualifies it as fair use. I will delete my comments above as they are not relevant to the question anymore and I don't plan to continue this conversation for the sake of staying on topic.